# Export SQLite3 to CSV with text representation of GUID/BLOB

Tags: csv, sqlite, blob, guid

I would like to export each table of my SQLite3 database to CSV files for further manipulation with Python and after that I want to export the CSV files into a different database format (PSQL). The ID column in SQLite3 is of type GUID, hence jiberrish when I export tables to CSV as text:

> l_yQ��rG�M�2�"�o

I know that there is a way to turn it into a readable format since the SQLite Manager addon for Firefox does this automatically, sadly without reference regarding how or which query is used:

> X'35B17880847326409E61DB91CC7B552E'

I know that QUOTE (GUID) displays the desired hexadecimal string, but I don't know how to dump it to the CSV instead of the BLOB.

Comment: How exactly are you creating the CSV?

Comment: See my answer post, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my error was - not why it doesn't work, but how I get around it.
So I tried to export my tables as staded in https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html , namely a multiline command, which didn't work:

```
sqlite3 'path_to_db'
.headers on`
.mode csv
.output outfile.csv
SELECT statement
```

and so on.

I was testing a few things and since I'm lazy while testing, I used the single line variant, which got the job done:

```
sqlite3 -header -csv 'path_to_db' "SELECT QUOTE (ID) AS Hex_ID, * FROM Table" > 'output_file.csv'
```

Of course it would be better if I would specify all column names instead of using *, but this sufices as an example.